# Compute the integral $(1-u)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} v^2\delta_0(v)dv$ + $u\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} v^2\delta_1(v)dv$

Tags: calculus, integration, dirac-delta

I have a function

(1) $E(u) = S(u) + u^2 = u(1-u) + u^2 = u$. We can compute $E(u)$ using the given integral:

$E(u) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} v^2(1-u)\delta_0(v)dv + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} v^2u\delta_1(v)dv = (1-u)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} v^2\delta_0(v)dv + u\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} v^2\delta_1(v)dv$.

I know that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(v)dv =1$ and we can also use the fact that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(v)\delta(v)dv = f(v)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(v)dv = f(0)$.

However I do not know how to proceed from this integral to get the same answer as in (1). I have never worked with an integral containing two "different" dirac delta functions. Since $f(0) = 0$ in both parts of the integral, I get $E(u) = 0$ instead of $E(u) =u$.

Any tips or any explanation would be gratefull. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
E(u) 
   &=& \displaystyle
   (1-u)\int_\mathbb{R}v^2\,\delta_0(v)\,\mathrm{d}v + u\int_\mathbb{R}v^2\,\delta_1(v)\,\mathrm{d}v \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   (1-u) \cdot \left.v^2\right|_{v=0} + u \cdot \left.v^2\right|_{v=1} = u
\end{array}
$$